# Jenkins kubernetes cloud service gettting SocketTimeoutException

Tags: linux, jenkins, kubernetes, routes

I'm building a continuous integration pipeline through Jenkins to deploy microservices on a kubernetes cluster. I'm using minikube implementation.

I have some error in kubernetes agent configuration. I created a secretText credential to allow the agent to connect to my K8s cluster but when I test it I get this error:

```
Error testing connection https://<my_k8s_cluster_ip>:8443: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

I don't understand what the problem is.

K8s agent config
[image]

minikube config :

```
root@minikube:~# kubectl config view --minify=true
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /root/.minikube/ca.crt
    extensions:
    - extension:
        last-update: Tue, 16 Feb 2021 23:57:36 CET
        provider: minikube.sigs.k8s.io
        version: v1.17.1
      name: cluster_info
    server: https://<minikube_ip>:8443
  name: minikube
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: minikube
    extensions:
    - extension:
        last-update: Tue, 16 Feb 2021 23:57:36 CET
        provider: minikube.sigs.k8s.io
        version: v1.17.1
      name: context_info
    namespace: bargo
    user: minikube
  name: minikube
current-context: minikube
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: minikube
  user:
    client-certificate: /root/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.crt
    client-key: /root/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.key
```

Secret

```
root@minikube:~# kubectl get secrets
NAME                  TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
db-user-pass          Opaque                                2      2d18h
default-token-4f7lh   kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      3d
jenkins-token-4kdgr   kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      2d18h
```

Listening port

```
root@minikube:~# sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17207/systemd-resol
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      633/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:49153         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26838/docker-proxy
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:49154         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26851/docker-proxy
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:49155         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26865/docker-proxy
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:49156         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26879/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      633/sshd: /usr/sbin
```

iptable result :

```
root@minikube:~# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8443

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             <my_server_ip>         tcp dpt:8443
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             <my_server_ip>         tcp dpt:5000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             <my_server_ip>         tcp dpt:2376
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             <my_server_ip>         tcp dpt:ssh

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Ubuntu Firewal status :

```
root@minikube:~# sudo ufw status verbose
Status: inactive
```

It's seam the Kubernetes API wasen't expose on port 8443. So i use this command :

```
kubectl proxy --port=8080 &
```

When i try it :

```
root@minikube:~# curl http://localhost:8080/api/
{
  "kind": "APIVersions",
  "versions": [
    "v1"
  ],
  "serverAddressByClientCIDRs": [
    {
      "clientCIDR": "0.0.0.0/0",
      "serverAddress": "<minikube_ip>:8443"
    }
  ]
}

root@minikube:~# curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/
{
  "kind": "APIVersions",
  "versions": [
    "v1"
  ],
  "serverAddressByClientCIDRs": [
    {
      "clientCIDR": "0.0.0.0/0",
      "serverAddress": "<minikube_ip>:8443"
    }
  ]
}

root@minikube:~# curl http://<minikube_ip>:8080/api/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to <minikube_ip> port 8080: Connection refused
```

Comment: Check if the cluster is actually listening on the IP you're using and port 8443. You can do a simple curl to check. From your netstat, nothing is listening on 8443 - so it's no surprise you can't connect.

Comment: As you can see in the iptable the 8443 port seems open but not listening.

Comment: Yeah, it's good that it's open, but you need to check where your API is. I haven't used minikube in a long time so won't be able to help specific details, but check your kubeconfig file and try to get working configuration from there. And then investigate where it may fail when routing from jenkins. Essentially, your issue is that your k8s api endpoints are not exposed properly.

Comment: @taleodor your have right. The kubernetes api wasen't expose on 8443 port. So i use kubectl proxy --port=8080 & for expose it on 8080. Now when test the api using localhost or 127.0.0.1 that ok but on the K8s clueter ip i have connection refused.